# r regex Lookbehind Lookahead issue

Tags: regex, r, extract, stringr

I try to extract passages like `44.11.36.00-1` (precisely, `nn.nn.nn.nn-n`, where `n` stands for any number from 0-9) from text in R.

I want to extract passages if they are "sticked" to non-number marks:

- `44.11.36.00-1` extracted from `nsfghstighsl44.11.36.00-1vsdfgh` is OK
- `44.11.36.00-1` extracted from `fa0044.11.36.00-1000` is NOT

I have read that `str_extract_all` is not working with `Lookbehind` and `Lookahead` expressions, so I sadly came back to `grep`, but cannot deal with it:

```
> pattern1 <- "(?<![0-9]{1})[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1}(?![0-9]{1})"
> grep(pattern1, "dyj44.11.36.00-1aregjspotgji 44113600-1 agdtklj441136001 ", perl=TRUE, value = TRUE)

[1] "dyj44.11.36.00-1aregjspotgji 44113600-1 agdtklj441136001 "
```

which is not the result I expected.

I thought that:

- `(?<![0-9]{1})` means "match expression which is not preceeded by a number"
- `[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1}` stands for the expression I seek for
- `(?![0-9]{1})`  means "match expression which is not followed by a number"

Comment: `grep` does not extract substrings. You need `regmatches`.

Comment: Roland, could you please provide some quick example based on my code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS @Roland said in his comment, you need to use `regmatches` instead of `grep`

```
> s <- "nsfghstighsl44.11.36.00-1vsdfgh"
> m <- gregexpr("(?<![0-9]{1})[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1}(?![0-9]{1})", s, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(s, m)
[1] "44.11.36.00-1"
```

A reduced one,

```
> x <- c('nsfghstighsl44.11.36.00-1vsdfgh', 'fa0044.11.36.00-1000')
> m <- gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}-\\d(?!\\d)", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "44.11.36.00-1"
```

Comment: Thank you Avinash Raj for this answer! This does the trick :)

Comment: I noticed regexpr match only first occurence of the patter-matching substring. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Bingo! Avinash Raj, I am really grateful! :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need lookahead or lookbehind with this approach.  Just parenthesize the portion you want extracted:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- c("nsfghstighsl44.11.36.00-1vsdfgh", "fa0044.11.36.00-1000") # test data

pat <- "(^|\\D)(\\d{2}[.]\\d{2}[.]\\d{2}[.]\\d{2}-\\d)(\\D|$)"
strapply(x, pat, ~ ..2, simplify = c)

## "44.11.36.00-1"
```

Note that `~ ..2` is short for the function `function(...) ..2` which means grab the match to the second parenthesized portion in the regular expression.  We could also have written `function(x, y, z) y` or `x + y + z ~ y` .

**Note:** The question seems to say that a non-numeric must come directly before and after the string but based on comments that have since disappeared it appears that what was really wanted was that the string be either at the beginning or just after a non-number and must either be at the end or folowed by a non-number.  The answer has been so modified.

Comment: I have modified the answer to require that a non-number or beginning of string comes direcdtly before the match and that a non-number or end of string comes directly after it.